# Don't relocate the clicked tab to the left in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed (maybe recently) that when I click an open editor tab vscode moves it to the leftmost side. I would like to turn this feature off, so that when I click on a tab, it just makes it active at its own place.

I removed all my custom settings but still that is the behaviour.

Comment: Could that possibly be some extension doing that?  You could `Reload With Extensions Disabled` and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yes it was one of extensions, I tried the extensions bisect command and found that and disabled it